# Pixel 3 / 3 XL icons change

Tags: google-pixel-3-xl

Is it possible to change the pixel 3 / 3 XL icons to 3rd party icons on the stock launcher?

I understand its possible to change icons sets by installing new launchers. However, I would like to know if its possible to change icon set in stock launcher which comes with Pixel devices.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment you camt. However, there is a modified version of the Pixel launcher, [Rootless Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=amirz.rootless.nexuslauncher) that can use icon packs

> Features:
>
> - Search bar at the bottom
> - Wallpaper based theme selection
> - Regular Icon Packs
> - Adaptive Icon Packs, such as my Google Icons
> - Icon Shape selection on Android 8.0